# Load 2D array from a file with two columns

Tags: c++, arrays, file-io

I'm trying to input this data from `payroll.dat`:

```
40.0     10.00
38.5      9.50
16.0      7.50
42.5      8.25
22.5      9.50
40.0      8.00
38.0      8.00
40.0      9.00
44.0     11.75
```

Into a 2d array of class `payroll` objects.

Here's what I've erroneously attempted:

```
int count = 0;
const int numEmploy = 7;            // Number of employees
const int col = 2;                  // Number of categories
Payroll empData[numEmploy][col];    // Array to hold objects
ifstream inputFile;

    inputFile.open("payroll.dat");
    if (!inputFile)
        cout << "There was an error opening the file. Please make sure it exists." << endl;
    else
    {
        while(count < numEmploy && inputFile >> empData[][])
        {
            inputFile >> empData[count][0] >> empData[count][1];
            count++;
        }
    }
```

Ultimately I need to take the value in `payroll.dat` at the `[0][0]` position and multiply by `[0][1]`, then `[1][0]*[1][1]`, then `[2][0]*[2][1]`, etc. and display the results as gross pay.

I think my understanding of the `>>` operator is off. In this scenario is this the stream extraction, bitwise, or technically both?

My understanding of the narrative of what's happening is: As long as `count` is less than `numEmploy` AND `empData[][]` is receiving a value from `payroll.dat`, insert the first available chunk of data in `payroll.dat` into `empData[0][0]`, insert the second chunk (the chunk to the right of the first chunk) into `empData[0][1]`. Then loop back and insert the following chunk (next row, first column of `payroll.dat`) into `empData[1][0]`, followed by the chunk to the right into `empData[1][1]`. Continue this until `count` is greater than or equal to `numEmploy`. Then each `empData[#][#]` will be an object of class `Payroll`. At least this is what I WANT it to be :P

Is it even possible to do this? Or am I stuck using two different arrays?

Here is my entire code so far:

```
class Payroll
{
    private:

        double payRate;      // holds an employee hourly pay rate

        double hoursWorked;  // an employee's hours worked

    public:

        Payroll()  // empty constructor sets the payRate and hoursWorked to zero
        {
            payRate = hoursWorked = 0;
        }

        Payroll(double payR, double hoursW) //constructor checks for payR and hoursW to be positive
                    // and sets payRate and hours worked; sets to zero if negative values are provided
        {
            if (payR < 0) payR = 0;
            if (hoursW < 0) hoursW = 0;
        }

        void setPayRate(double payR) //mutator for payRate; checks for payR to be positive or sets to zero
        {
            payRate = payR;
        } 

        void setHoursWorked(double hoursW) //mutator for hoursWorked; checks for positive hoursW or sets to zero
        {
            hoursWorked = hoursW;
        }

        double getPayRate() //accessor to return payRate
        {
            return payRate;
        }

        double getHoursWorked() // accessor to return hoursWorked
        {
            return hoursWorked;
        }

        double getGrossPay() // computes and returns gross pay including OVERTIME, if any
        {
            float normHours, overHours, grossPay;

            if (hoursWorked > 40)
            {
                overHours = (hoursWorked - 40);
                normHours = (hoursWorked - overHours);
                grossPay = (overHours * payRate * 1.5) + (normHours * payRate);
            }

            return grossPay;

        }
};





int main ()
{
int count = 0;
const int numEmploy = 7;            // Number of employees
const int col = 2;                  // Number of categories
Payroll empData[numEmploy][col];    // Array to hold objects
ifstream inputFile;

inputFile.open("payroll.dat");
if (!inputFile)
    cout << "There was an error opening the file. Please make sure it exists." << endl;
else
{
    while(count < numEmploy && inputFile >> empData[][])
    {
        inputFile >> empData[count][0] >> empData[count][1];
        count++;
    }
}

inputFile.close();

cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2) << endl;

cout << "Employees' gross pay:" << endl;

for (int index = 0; index < numEmploy; index++)
{

    empData[index][2].setPayRate();
    empData[index][1].setHoursWorked();
    cout << "Employee # " << index + 1 << empData.getGrossPay();

}


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `inputFile >> empData[][]` supposed to do?

Comment: Should you define overload operator >> for class Payroll?

Comment: To be honest I have no idea. Took it from a sample problem in my book. I assumed it was making sure there is something to get from the file, but now that I look at it it doesn't make a lot of sense.. Unless the array is a vector? Which it isn't nor is it supposed to be.

Comment: @Duc that is interesting as that relates to the HUGE amount of errors I have been getting but couldn't make sense of.. Can you explain why I need to define it? It seems strange only because I've made 6 programs using `cin >>` and never had to define `>>`, however I'm not totally comfortable with the concept of overloading yet.

Comment: You don't need a 2d array, you need an array of Payroll objects and an overloaded `operator>>` to read the hours and rate from the file into each object.

Comment: @CoreyStarbird: looking at this **inputFile >> empData[count][0] >> empData[count][1];**, I think that you're reading the doubles for **hourWorked** and **payRate** line by line. But, your **empData** is a 2-dimension-array of class **Payroll**, it's not a double variables. Every element in the array is a **Payroll** object. And in class Payroll, I didn't see where operator **>>** is defined.

Comment: @Ninja This may seem silly, but I thought that's what I was doing..

Comment: @CoreyStarbird: plz take a look at this link [istream::operator >>](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/). The list contain data types that are understood by **istream::operator >>**. It doesn't know what to do with an object of class **Payroll**. So, you have to define one if you want to use it.

Comment: Ok, I now see why it doesn't know what to do with `operator>>` but my book doesn't cover this concept. Can you help me make sense of this?

`istream& operator>> (ostream& ostr, const string& output){return ostr >> output.data;}`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something a little more like this,

```
Payroll empData[numEmploy] ;

...

while ( count < numEmploy )
{
  inputFile >> empdata[count].payRate >> empdata[count].hoursWorked ;
  count ++ ;
}
```

Then your pay is just `empdata[x].payRate * empdata[x].hoursworked`

If the reading loop is not in a member function of Payroll, then you have to use the setters:

```
while ( count < numEmploy )
{
  double tmppay, tmphours ;
  inputFile >> tmppay >> tmphours ;
  empdata[count].setPayRate( tmppay ) ;
  empdata[count].setHoursWorked( tmphours) ;
  count ++ ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I figured I was making it way more complicated than I should. Now that I see it it makes sense. The concept of set and get member functions just clicked while looking at this too.

Comment: So let me try to put this into words. At `Payroll empData[numEmploy]`, this makes `empData[]` an array of 7 objects of class `Payroll`. Because of the constructor, each instance(?) of the `empData` array is set at `payRate=hoursWorked=0`.....mid thought I realized you're "dotting" to the member variable and setting it directly. It all makes complete sense now. This is only my 2nd program working with classes and objects. I hadn't done this yet. THANK YOU AGAIN!

Comment: If I declare my array `Payroll empData[numEmploy]` then define the elements using `empData[count]` will the compiler think they are two different object arrays? Because I'm getting a "Private member" type thing now.

Comment: They are private, look at where you declared them in your class.  You can read to a temporary value and then use your set functions or use `operator>>` in your class.

Comment: I was under the impression private is only private for anything outside the class. Since `empData` is of class `Payroll`, why wouldn't `empData[count].payRate()` have access to it?

Comment: The while loop has to "belong" to Payroll to be able to access private parts.  Otherwise you have to use the setters.

Comment: Thank you everybody for the help by the way